# Doesn't get Windows Phone emulator keypad for input

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-7.1, xbox360

I am developing game for windows phone. I select project Windows Phone Game(4.0). 
Write some code for moving object on windows phone emulator  but I didn't get keypad for giving input to that object. 
I also import following files.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
```

Why I didn't get keypad on Windows phone Emulator?

Comment: Which action did you try to perform to make the keyboard appear? It normally only comes out when you select an input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, it should work in XNA, Silverlight and Silverlight/XNA

http://luisguerrero.net/en/2010/07/17/how-to-access-to-keyboard-in-xna-from-windows-phone-7/

Comment: To make this a proper answer, consider copying in the relevant sections of code from your link?